# Calculate centerline in 3d structure

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I have a 3D-matrix of a segmented (pathological) trachea. The 3D-matrix consists of multiple tranversal binary slices. Using matlab I construct a 3D-visualization of the trachea using the following code:

```
xVec = 1:size(matrix,2);
yVec = 1:size(matrix,1);
zVec = 1:size(matrix,3);
axis equal
hold on
W = smooth3(matrix,'box',5);
p = patch(isosurface(xVec,yVec,zVec,W));
isonormals(xVec,yVec,zVec,matrix,p);
set(p,'FaceColor',[0.7 0.05 0.05],'Edgecolor','none');
daspect('auto')
view([-12.5 24]);
camlight HEADLIGHT
lighting gouraud
lightangle(160,20)
set(gca,'ZDir','reverse');
material([1 1 1])
axis off
set(gca,'color','none')
```

Which generates images like this:

[image: Pathological trachea]

I'm interested in the diameter of the trachea throughout its course, at this moment I use [regionprops](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to calculate the diameter for each transversal slice but as you can see the trachea is curved which causes me to overestimate the diameter at the portion of the trachea with a lot of deviation. I think I need to calculate a 3d-centerline and then calculte the diameter perpendicular to this centerline but I don't know an efficient way to do this. Can anybody help me out? Thank you very much.

Update:
I thought of a solution but its results are sub-optimal. Using the [bwmorph](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) function I find the border of the structure for each slice(thus the trachea Lumen). Thereafter I subtract this border from the original matrix which leaves me with all elements which are situated inside of the trachea.
For each slice I collect all elements inside of the trachea, thereafter I check the distance for all these elements within a certain slice to the closest element within the entire trachea Lumen. I regard the element within that slice whereby this distance to the closest lumen-element is the biggest to be the center for that specific slice. The result is as follows:
[image: Trachea with centerline]

As you can see the centerline is quite squiggly. I think this is caused by the fact that my matrix has quite a low resolution (the 3D-structure looks quite good due to smoothing). Moreover with the translation from grayscale (my dicom image) to binary I trow out a lot of useful information. So I guess a way to improve my results would be to use an algorithm which also accounts for the intensity of pixels within a image. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43400-skeleton3d ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an oversimplification but could you not use a for loop to index through your Z matrix and for each level use something like then use idx2sub() to create a polygon slice of the image. Then the following package might help you find the center (CenterX and CenterY) of the polygon slice.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/319-polygeom-m

After that it would be a simple matter of using diameter=(abs(max(X-ceterX))+abs(min(X-centerX)).

Good luck and what great image!

Comment: This would result in the centre of the slices in the XY-plane, which is not necessarily the centre of the three-dimensional shape.